# How to create ASCII animation in a console application using Python 3.x?

Tags: animation, python-3.x, console-application, ascii-art

I would like to port this question to Python (Windows + Linux + Mac Os)

[How to create ASCII animation in Windows Console application using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725529/how-to-create-ascii-animation-in-windows-console-application-using-c)

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just ported my example with the animated gif to ASCII animation from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725529/how-to-create-ascii-animation-in-windows-console-application-using-c/2725584#2725584) to python. You will need to install the pyglet library from [here](http://www.pyglet.org/download.html), as python unfortunately has no built-in animated-gif support. Hope you like it :)

```
import pyglet, sys, os, time

def animgif_to_ASCII_animation(animated_gif_path):
    # map greyscale to characters
    chars = ('#', '#', '@', '%', '=', '+', '*', ':', '-', '.', ' ')
    clear_console = 'clear' if os.name == 'posix' else 'CLS'

    # load image
    anim = pyglet.image.load_animation(animated_gif_path)

    # Step through forever, frame by frame
    while True:
        for frame in anim.frames:

            # Gets a list of luminance ('L') values of the current frame
            data = frame.image.get_data('L', frame.image.width)

            # Built up the string, by translating luminance values to characters
            outstr = ''
            for (i, pixel) in enumerate(data):
                outstr += chars[(ord(pixel) * (len(chars) - 1)) / 255] + \
                          ('\n' if (i + 1) % frame.image.width == 0 else '')

            # Clear the console
            os.system(clear_console)

            # Write the current frame on stdout and sleep
            sys.stdout.write(outstr)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)

# run the animation based on some animated gif
animgif_to_ASCII_animation(u'C:\\some_animated_gif.gif')
```

Comment: Didnt test it with python 3.x, only got 2.6 on my PC. If anyone could test that on 3.x: would be great.

Comment: I've tried this on python 3.5.2, but unfortunately compiler states that there is an error like this: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found . Some of the answers in SO states that ord() function should be deleted. but when you did that, it also breaks from the same line as: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not float. So I believe I need someone to test this too :)

Comment: That's an old post. But still, 21st line should be: "outstr += chars[int((pixel * (len(chars) - 1)) / 255)] + \". But enumerate(data) takes pixels from the bottom to the top, so animation in a console is upside down.

Answer (score 10):

This is precisely the sort of application that I created [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) for.

It is a cross-platform console API with support for generating animated scenes from a rich set of text effects.  It has been proved to work on various flavours of CentOS and Windows and OSX.

Samples of what is possible are available from the [gallery](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/wiki).  Here's a sample similar to the animated GIF code provided in other answers.

[image: Colour images]

I assume you're just looking for a way to do any animation, but if you really wanted to replicate the steam train, you could convert it to a Sprite and give it a Path that just runs it across the Screen, then play it as part of a Scene.  Full explanations of the objects can be found in the [docs](http://asciimatics.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Simple console animation, tested on python3 in Ubuntu.
addch() doesn't like that non-ascii character, but it works in addstr().

```
#this comment is needed in windows:
#  encoding=latin-1
def curses(win):
    from curses import use_default_colors, napms, curs_set
    use_default_colors()
    win.border()
    curs_set(0)

    row, col = win.getmaxyx()
    anim = '.-+^°*'
    y = int(row / 2)
    x = int((col - len(anim))/2)
    while True:
        for i in range(6):
            win.addstr(y, x+i, anim[i:i+1])
            win.refresh()
            napms(100)
            win.addch(y, x+i, ' ')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from curses import wrapper
    wrapper(curses)
```

---

@Philip Daubmeier: I've tested this under Windoze and it doesn't work :(. There's three basic options going forward: (please choose)

1. Install a third-party windows-curses library (http://adamv.com/dev/python/curses/)
2. Apply a windows-curses patch to python (http://bugs.python.org/msg94309)
3. Abandon curses altogether for something else.

Comment: did you install pyglet? Which error message showed up? I tested it like I said on windows with python 2.6 and `cmd` console and it worked.

Comment: BTW: you dont necessarily need to use curses, like you see in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Colorama:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Comment: -1 for posting a single link as an answer to a question with 100 bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I managed to port Philip Daubmeier's solution to python 3 (and also added color mapping to it). The main problem was the ord-function, which needed to be left out, as Python 3 - bytestring indexing returns the ASCII-value directly, instead of the char at that position (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260954/why-does-ord-fail-when-porting-from-python-2-to-python-3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774496/python-2-to-python-3)..).
I created a Git repo, feel free to contribute (better performance would be desirable-> pm for invitation):

**repo**: https://github.com/sebibek/gif2ascii