# How to make a Python (2.7.x) program output nethack-like ASCII graphics?

Tags: python, animation, ascii-art, nethack

I'm looking to make a console game which would constantly need to output frames of ASCII graphics, but I'm wondering how to make the function much smoother. While I don't believe the `nethack-console` game isn't written in Python, I'm looking at how well it can display 'animated' frames which don't seem to move around, and not clearly showing that the graphics were 'reprinted', in turn making the graphics very consistent, and any animation that happens 'seems to be done on a single print-out'. If the description isn't clear enough, let me use examples:

`000X`

If the 'x' would move one unit to the left, I'd like to see this on the console:

`00X0`

and not:

`000X
 00X0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create ASCII animation in a console application using Python 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726343/how-to-create-ascii-animation-in-a-console-application-using-python-3-x)

Comment: Eventually you could try to use `\r` in place of `\n` - and you will have to and `,` in `print` - like `print '\r000X',` and then `print '\r00X0',`. But thera are better solution like `curses`

Answer (score 3):

Check out [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module, or [urwid](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urwid) library, very good begning to start with console applications. Curses (and urwid) allows you to draw frame in buffer and then update screen only in places where it's needed.

Comment: In my experience curses is usually the best option for doing such stuff.